# More parallel actors in scala

Tags: scala, concurrency, akka

(sort of followup to [How to make a code thread safe in scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10718255/how-to-make-a-code-thread-safe-in-scala) )

I have a scala class that can inherently be called only from one thread (let's call it `class ThreadUnsafeProducer`); it is, however, safe to have more threads to each access exactly one object. However, the `ThreadUnsafeProducer` is quite memory heavy, so I don't want each thread to have one `ThreadUnsafeProducer`.

I want to have a given number `N` of `ThreadUnsafeProducer` objects (ideally one for each CPU).

I have lots of threads `Consumer` that all share the same object `SharedObject`.

I want to somehow use Actors model to give messages to either  `SharedObject` or `ThreadUnsafeProducer` (I am not sure which) to have a given number of concurrent `ThreadUnsafeProducer` running. And I am quite lost in all the Akka/Actors classes.

Comment: This might be something very basic; I never used Actors model before.

Comment: I'd recommend asking the question on the akka-user mailing list (http://groups.google.com/group/akka-user/). And add the akka tag to this question.

Comment: What exactly is the question? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently found Akka Routing classes

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0/scala/routing.html

It looks really nice and exactly what I need. If it works it would be beautiful.