# singleton concept in Scala

Tags: scala

How to implement the getDataStore method as singleton method(threadsafe) in a Scala object or Scala's object will implement this method automatically as a singleton method?

```
object MorphiaHelper {
  var morphia = new Morphia()
  var datastore = null
  def getDataStore() = {morphia.createDatastore(new Mongo(mongoip, mongoport), "test")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not completely sure what you mean by *singleton method(threadsafe)*, so here come some variants/facts you might care about:

1. MorphiaHelper is a singleton since you made it an object. Nothing to do here
2. the method getDataStore() is not thread safe. To make it thread safe see this Question: [How to make a code thread safe in scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10718255/how-to-make-a-code-thread-safe-in-scala)
3. if you want to make sure that there is only one instance of datastore, initialized using the return value of getDataStore, you can rewrite the object like this:

   ```
   object MorphiaHelper {
     lazy val datastore = (new Morphia()).createDatastore(
         new Mongo(mongoip, mongoport), "test")
   }
   ```

   This will create only one data store [when it is requested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7484928/what-does-a-lazy-val-do) and it [will be thread safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095170/scala-lazy-values-performance-penalty-threadsafe).

Comment: make it `lazy val` so that it is called when requested

Comment: @DenisTulskiy oops, that was what I intended. Fixed it.